# Reconfigure the adsl router

Tags: adsl-router

My internet suddenly stopped. My internet provider is Acanac.

So I decided to reset the router, which from TP-LINK.
Then I went into the  Ip address: 192.168.1.1 and then after authentification and all 
I got into this page:
[image]

So I’m wondering what do I do now to set it up? Like what do I do next? for example do I enable broadcast SSID?

On the router, the dsl light is on but the internet light is off

Comment: Did you call your ISP? They could have been through issues.

Comment: Those are the settings for *your* Wi-Fi network. You can set it up however you like. If at all possible you should use WPA2.

Comment: FYI the advice to "reset the router" means to turn it off for a few seconds and then back on. Resetting to factory settings doesn't solve anything 99% of time. These are your WiFi settings and you can configure them to your needs (which is probably broadcast SSID + WPA2), but on the next step you'll have to enter connection details which have to match credentials from your ISP.